# save rhandsontable to .Rda

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I am trying to generate a simple table and save the user inputted values to an Rda file. I am getting the error... Any help would be very much appreciated.

> Warning: Error in : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(lubridate)

test_db <- data.frame(d = 20:52,
                      date = seq(ymd("2020/05/15"), by = "7 days", length.out = 33), 
                      i = vector("numeric", length = 33),
                      p = vector("numeric", length = 33),
                      t = vector("numeric", length = 33),
                      dm = vector("numeric", length = 33)
                      )


save(test_db, file = "test_db.Rda")


ui <- fluidPage(


  mainPanel(
    rHandsontableOutput('table'),
    actionButton("save", "Save Changes")
  )
) 


server <- function(input, output){

  data1 = load("test_db.Rda")

  output$table = renderRHandsontable(data1)



  saveData <- function(){
    finalDF <- hot_to_r( input$table )
    save(finalDF, file = "test_db.Rda")
  }

  observeEvent(input$save, saveData())



}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you misuse `load()` or mix up [RData and RDS](https://yihui.org/en/2017/12/save-vs-saverds/). `load()` loads all objects that have been stored in that file into the workspace invisibly. The return value of `load()` is as described in `?load()`:

> A character vector of the names of objects created, invisibly.

Therefore, **not** the objects themselves are assigned, but just their names! You will be, almost always, be better of to use RDS files.

Does this code satisfy your needs?

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(lubridate)

test_db <- data.frame(d = 20:52,
                      date = seq(ymd("2020/05/15"), by = "7 days", length.out = 33), 
                      i = vector("numeric", length = 33),
                      p = vector("numeric", length = 33),
                      t = vector("numeric", length = 33),
                      dm = vector("numeric", length = 33)
)
saveRDS(test_db, file = "test_db.RDS")

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    actionButton("save", "Save Changes"),
    rHandsontableOutput('table')
  )
) 

server <- function(input, output){
  data1 <- readRDS("test_db.RDS")

  # render must contain a rhandsontable, not just the data
  my_handsomtable <- rhandsontable(data1)
  output$table  <- renderRHandsontable(my_handsomtable)

  saveData <- function(){
    finalDF <- hot_to_r(input$table)
    saveRDS(finalDF, file = "test_db.RDS")
  }

  observeEvent(input$save, saveData())
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: is there a way to enter =sum(range:range) or =a1 + a2 similar to excel?

Comment: well, the underlying table is just a data frame. so you can use data frame syntax. `data1[1:2, "a"]`